# Why is the hover effect "disabled" when i hover it to the text?

Tags: html, css

In the code, the text should be involved in the hover, but when I hovered the text, there was no effect. Is there any problem with my code?

Note: I know the positioning might be ruined in importing or fixing the code, but it's okay I might be able to fix it. Also, I tried applying a hover effect on the text but still no effect

```css
body{
margin-left: 8em;
margin-right: 8em;
}

.pseudo-selector{
position: relative;
}

.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  background:
  linear-gradient(
  rgba(24,39,61,0.50),
  rgba(24,39,61,0.90)
  ),
  url('math.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
h1{
 position: absolute;
 font-family: Lato;
 font-size: 25px;
    top: 50%;
 left: 25%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 10;
 }
#text{
 font-family: Open Sans;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 40px;
 }
 
.container:hover{
 background: url('https://www.superprof.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/maths-methods-700x467.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 transition-timing-function: ease;
 color: black;
 }
h1: hover{
 background: url('https://www.superprof.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/maths-methods-700x467.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 transition-timing-function: ease;
 color: black;
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="pseudo-selector">
<img class="container">
 <h1><div id="text">Math</div>Enjoy the wonders of solving through fun problems.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: you have this in your code `h1: hover`. remove the space between `h1:` and `hover` and check if that was the problem, then check that ìmg` tag is not a container for others elements

Comment: h1 should still hover for the whole image tho

Comment: you code is not correct... check it out...

Comment: The <img> tag defines an image in an HTML page. The <img> tag has two required attributes: src and alt. Note: Images are not technically inserted into an HTML page, images are linked to HTML pages. The <img> tag creates a holding space for the referenced image. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: i know it's wrong, and i just can't find out what is wrong (even if i remove h1:hover, still wrong tho)

Comment: ohhhhhh okay nvm

Answer (score 0):

It is better to do a hover on the parent, so when you are hover any childs. The background is goign to work.
The good code:

```css
    body{
    margin-left: 8em;
    margin-right: 8em;
    }

    .pseudo-selector{
    position: relative;
    }

    .container {
      display: block;
      height: 500px;
      width: 50%;
      background:
      linear-gradient(
      rgba(24,39,61,0.50),
      rgba(24,39,61,0.90)
      ),
      url('math.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
    h1{
     position: absolute;
     font-family: Lato;
     font-size: 25px;
        top: 50%;
     left: 25%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     margin: auto;
     z-index: 10;
     }
    #text{
     font-family: Open Sans;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 40px;
     }
     
    .pseudo-selector:hover .container{
     background: url('https://www.superprof.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/maths-methods-700x467.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     transition: all 0.5s;     
      transition-timing-function: ease;
     color: black;
     }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="pseudo-selector">
      <span class="container"></span>
     <h1><div id="text">Math</div>Enjoy the wonders of solving through fun problems.</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can't use `img` in that way

Comment: oh yeah! it's now better i think